# Asp.Net MVC Return to page on error with fields populated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am starting a new project in Asp.net MVC 2.
I have been mostly a webforms developer and have limited exposure to Asp.Net MVC and hence this is probably a noob question.

My situation is as follows:
I have a create page for saving some data to the DB.
The view for this page is not strongly bound / typed - so the way I am extracting the data from the view is by looking at the POST parameters.

Incase there is an error (data validation, etc), I need to send the user back to the previous page with everything filled in the way it was and displaying the message.

On webforms, this got handled automatically due to the view state - but how can I go about doing the same here?

A code example can be as follows:

**View:**

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Question", FormMethod.Post)) { %>
<div>
Title: <%: Html.TextBox("Title", "", new { @style="width:700px" })%>
</div>
<div>
Question: <%: Html.TextBox("Question", "", new { @style="width:700px" })%>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% } %>
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create() {
        Question q = new Question();
        q.Title = Request.Form["Title"];
        q.Text = Request.Form["Question"];
        if(q.Save()) {
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = q.Id });
        }
        else {
            // Need to send back to Create page with data filled in
            // Help needed here
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply return the View in case of error. This will preserve the context.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Create(Question q) {
    if(q.Save()) {
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = q.Id });
    }
    else {
        // Need to send back to Create page with data filled in
        // Help needed here
        return View();
        // If the view is located on some other controller you could
        // specify its location:
        // return View("~/Views/Question/Create.aspx");
    }
}
```

Also I would recommend you to use strongly typed views along with the strongly typed helpers. Notice how I used a `Question` object directly as action parameter. This is equivalent to the code you have written in which you were manually extracting and building this object. The model binder does this job automatically for you.

Comment: Hey Darin! Thanks for the super quick reply - but this is not working for me. I am able to redirect to the page, but the input fields are blank. Is there anything I need to do differently with the View Code that I pasted above?

Comment: You don't need to redirect. If there are errors you return a View as I showed in the else section. This way the context will be preserved. If you redirect you will lose the context. In case of success you should store the values into the database and then redirect by passing only the id (as you have already did), so in the Details action you could use this id to fetch the values you have stored from the database.

Comment: I did not mean "redirect". Sorry for the miscommunication. What I am doing is the following: return View("~/Views/Question/Ask.aspx"); as per your suggestion - but the view does not retain any of the data that was posted to the controller. I even tried chaning: <%: Html.TextBox("Title", "", new { @style="width:700px" })%> to <%: Html.TextBox("Title")%> but the earlier values just blank out. I am sure it is a very standard thing and I am missing some stuff. Thanks.

Comment: @saurabhj, when returning a view it should retain values that were posted. So for example, if there was a `Title` value in the POST request and you have used `<%: Html.TextBox("Title")%>` inside the returned view it will automatically populate it with the value.

Comment: And how do you display an error message? Set a flag and message in your ViewData?